# Snowflake Azure Storage integration not authorized

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage

I want to load data via automated loading from an azure storage account to snowflake.
I used this guideline to implement the integration:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-azure.html#step-2-create-an-integration-in-snowflake
I can access the data in the storage after the Stage is created.

In the last step i want to create the pipa via this commad:

**create or replace pipe factory_data 
auto_ingest = true 
integration = 'azure_int'
as copy into SENSOR(json)
from (select $1 from @azure_factory_stage)
file_format=(type=json);**

unfortunately i get this error:

**"SQL compilation error: Integration '"azure_int"' does not exist or not authorized."**

The integration exists.

Anyone got a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with all caps Integration name.

```
create or replace pipe factory_data 
auto_ingest = true 
integration = 'AZURE_INT' 
as copy into SENSOR(json) from (select $1 from @azure_factory_stage) file_format=(type=json);
```

From a [completely unrelated page](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/system_generate_scim_access_token.html):

> Note that the integration name is case-sensitive and must be uppercase and enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If this didn't work, you can see the Snowflake documentation [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Troubleshoot-integration-does-not-exist) which explains how to reassign the storage integration to a stage if you've had to recreate the storage integration for whatever reason. The reason (in my case) that the create pipe didn't work is because i had to recreate the storage integration, which changed the ID that is used by the stage to refer to the storage integration. After using the following it worked perfectly:
ALTER STAGE <stage_name> SET STORAGE_INTEGRATION = storage_integration_name